# Word prediction in mobile application

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm working on a project that is to develop a mobile application (android) which can be used to make a communication between normal people and auditory impaired people. We hope to do this using finger spelling. I developed a fingertip tracking code using OpenCv with C++. What I needed is to identify the correct letters when acting the sign which is relevant to the letter.
That image processing part is working as I want. But the thing is all the letters cannot be detected using this code. Only 15 letters can be detected. Can someone tell me how to detect other letters?? Does anyone know about word prediction??Means since we cannot detect all the letters we have to give some suitable words to the user. Then the user will select the word that he want. If someone know how this can be done let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explore other forms of languages like python?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C++ question, rather it is kind of algorithm of movement tracking. You haven't tell which letters detected and which are not. If you app reads finger movement on the touch screen, I guess the algorithm should be something similar to those used by pattern/character recognition software. Try google those to see if any can help. Or you have to show your algorithm in order for people to figure out why letters not detected.